# media player with subtitle development in c#

Tags: c#

I am trying to write a media player with WMPLib and interfaces.I want to attach subtitle when a video (.avi , mpeg etc) is playing.

Any algorithm or code? need help....

Comment: any full source code sample ?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at it. http://code.google.com/p/subtitleedit/